# not using index on more interval postgrasql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have 3 tables the number of record in this table is below.

```
select count(1) from device_data.raw; -- 33,67,66,948

select count(1) from device_data.internal_sensors; --29,36,05,529

select count(1) from device_data.calibrated;--32,00,97,945
```

if I run the below query

```
SELECT
    raw."time",
    raw.device,
    raw.therm_temp,
    raw.therm_temp_sd,
    raw."temp",
    cal.tair,
    cal.tair_version,
    cal.rh,
    i_s.t_u14,
    i_s.t_u21from device_data.calibrated cal
    JOIN device_data.raw raw ON cal."time" = raw."time"
        AND cal.device = raw.device
        AND cal."location" = raw."location"
    JOIN device_data.internal_sensors i_s ON cal.device = i_s.device
        AND cal."location" = i_s."location"
        AND cal."time" = i_s.time
WHERE
    cal.time >= now() - interval '100 day'
```

all join conditions and filter condition are pk column.

if I run the above query with interval 10 days. it will use the index and
I am getting the output immediately.

```
Type: Gather; ; Cost: 1001.85 - 9794496.92
Type: Nested Loop (Inner); ; Cost: 1.85 - 9793496.82
Type: Nested Loop (Inner); ; Cost: 1.15 - 9793488.56
Type: Parallel Index Scan; Rel: calibrated ; Cost: 0.58 - 2553907.35
Type: Index Scan; Rel: internal_sensors ; Cost: 0.57 - 8.11
Type: Index Scan; Rel: raw ; Cost: 0.70 - 8.24`
```

if I run the same query with interval 100 or above it is not using index.

```
Type: Gather; ; Cost: 10997796.65 - 22328719.05
Type: Nested Loop (Inner); ; Cost: 10996796.65 - 22327718.95
Type: Parallel Hash Join (Inner); ; Cost: 10996795.96 - 22327702.46
Type: Parallel Seq Scan; Rel: internal_sensors ; Cost: 0.00 - 11039189.85
Type: Parallel Hash; ; Cost: 10831915.70 - 10831915.70
Type: Parallel Seq Scan; Rel: calibrated ; Cost: 0.00 - 10831915.70
Type: Index Scan; Rel: raw ; Cost: 0.70 - 8.24`
```

I am getting output after 10 min if I give the interval 360 days
takes more than 5 hours.

please help me on how to solve this

explain plan for 10 day interval

```
Gather  (cost=1001.85..9670267.42 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.509..745226.202 rows=9067714 loops=1)
  Output: raw."time", raw.device, raw.therm_temp, raw.therm_temp_sd, raw.temp, cal.tair, cal.tair_version, cal.rh, i_s.t_u14, i_s.t_u21
  Workers Planned: 5
  Workers Launched: 5
  Buffers: shared hit=99973969 read=4810639
  I/O Timings: read=33748395.560
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.85..9669267.32 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.200..743715.367 rows=1511286 loops=6)
        Output: raw."time", raw.device, raw.therm_temp, raw.therm_temp_sd, raw.temp, cal.tair, cal.tair_version, cal.rh, i_s.t_u14, i_s.t_u21
        Inner Unique: true
        Join Filter: ((cal."time" = raw."time") AND (cal.device = raw.device) AND (cal.location = raw.location))
        Buffers: shared hit=99973969 read=4810639
        I/O Timings: read=33748395.560
        Worker 0: actual time=0.101..744096.095 rows=1512339 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=16671138 read=801662
          I/O Timings: read=5690629.974
        Worker 1: actual time=0.108..744178.103 rows=1512591 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=16677843 read=802658
          I/O Timings: read=5550919.933
        Worker 2: actual time=0.712..744165.762 rows=1512841 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=16679836 read=801947
          I/O Timings: read=5665561.534
        Worker 3: actual time=0.114..744080.538 rows=1515365 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=16707275 read=803410
          I/O Timings: read=5617567.579
        Worker 4: actual time=0.101..744133.690 rows=1505928 loops=1
          Buffers: shared hit=16602313 read=802074
          I/O Timings: read=5531045.600
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.15..9669259.07 rows=1 width=115) (actual time=0.158..352297.308 rows=1511286 loops=6)
              Output: cal.tair, cal.tair_version, cal.rh, cal."time", cal.device, cal.location, i_s.t_u14, i_s.t_u21, i_s.device, i_s.location, i_s."time"
              Inner Unique: true
              Buffers: shared hit=47300501 read=2905220
              I/O Timings: read=7712080.552
              Worker 0: actual time=0.079..352191.498 rows=1512340 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=7886345 read=483831
                I/O Timings: read=1308459.669
              Worker 1: actual time=0.088..352358.497 rows=1512591 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=7891226 read=484819
                I/O Timings: read=1194998.833
              Worker 2: actual time=0.561..352774.681 rows=1512841 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=7891350 read=484415
                I/O Timings: read=1248616.239
              Worker 3: actual time=0.089..352490.425 rows=1515366 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=7904173 read=485468
                I/O Timings: read=1349107.087
              Worker 4: actual time=0.081..352461.215 rows=1505928 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=7855768 read=484320
                I/O Timings: read=1262171.500
              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using idx_caltimedesc on device_data.calibrated cal  (cost=0.58..2521559.02 rows=881210 width=59) (actual time=0.134..15419.582 rows=1547766 loops=6)
                    Output: cal.tair, cal.tair_version, cal.rh, cal."time", cal.device, cal.location
                    Index Cond: (cal."time" >= (now() - '10 days'::interval))
                    Buffers: shared hit=418910 read=1256690
                    I/O Timings: read=5809154.203
                    Worker 0: actual time=0.056..15531.181 rows=1548555 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=69465 read=209576
                      I/O Timings: read=991509.608
                    Worker 1: actual time=0.062..15490.237 rows=1549215 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=70003 read=209910
                      I/O Timings: read=877883.648
                    Worker 2: actual time=0.532..15342.439 rows=1549390 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=69837 read=209064
                      I/O Timings: read=930936.107
                    Worker 3: actual time=0.065..15353.238 rows=1551856 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=70498 read=210653
                      I/O Timings: read=1031704.646
                    Worker 4: actual time=0.057..15392.558 rows=1542332 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=69263 read=209137
                      I/O Timings: read=944736.112
              ->  Index Scan using idx_time_dev_loc on device_data.internal_sensors i_s  (cost=0.57..8.11 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=0.215..0.215 rows=1 loops=9286595)
                    Output: i_s.t_u14, i_s.t_u21, i_s.device, i_s.location, i_s."time"
                    Index Cond: ((i_s."time" = cal."time") AND ((i_s.device)::text = cal.device) AND ((i_s.location)::text = cal.location))
                    Buffers: shared hit=45733772 read=1648530
                    I/O Timings: read=1902926.349
                    Worker 0: actual time=0.215..0.215 rows=1 loops=1548555
                      Buffers: shared hit=7626337 read=274255
                      I/O Timings: read=316950.061
                    Worker 1: actual time=0.215..0.215 rows=1 loops=1549215
                      Buffers: shared hit=7629547 read=274909
                      I/O Timings: read=317115.184
                    Worker 2: actual time=0.216..0.216 rows=1 loops=1549390
                      Buffers: shared hit=7629938 read=275351
                      I/O Timings: read=317680.132
                    Worker 3: actual time=0.215..0.215 rows=1 loops=1551856
                      Buffers: shared hit=7642542 read=274815
                      I/O Timings: read=317402.441
                    Worker 4: actual time=0.216..0.216 rows=1 loops=1542332
                      Buffers: shared hit=7595028 read=275183
                      I/O Timings: read=317435.388
        ->  Index Scan using raw_pk on device_data.raw  (cost=0.70..8.24 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.256..0.256 rows=1 loops=9067717)
              Output: raw."time", raw.device, raw.therm_temp, raw.therm_temp_sd, raw.temp, raw.location
              Index Cond: ((raw."time" = i_s."time") AND (raw.device = (i_s.device)::text) AND (raw.location = (i_s.location)::text))
              Buffers: shared hit=52673468 read=1905419
              I/O Timings: read=26036315.008
              Worker 0: actual time=0.256..0.256 rows=1 loops=1512340
                Buffers: shared hit=8784793 read=317831
                I/O Timings: read=4382170.305
              Worker 1: actual time=0.256..0.256 rows=1 loops=1512591
                Buffers: shared hit=8786617 read=317839
                I/O Timings: read=4355921.100
              Worker 2: actual time=0.256..0.256 rows=1 loops=1512841
                Buffers: shared hit=8788486 read=317532
                I/O Timings: read=4416945.295
              Worker 3: actual time=0.256..0.256 rows=1 loops=1515366
                Buffers: shared hit=8803102 read=317942
                I/O Timings: read=4268460.492
              Worker 4: actual time=0.257..0.257 rows=1 loops=1505928
                Buffers: shared hit=8746545 read=317754
                I/O Timings: read=4268874.101
Planning Time: 4.538 ms
```

If I run this query it is running only I am not getting any result.(almost it is running 5 hours).

```
explain (analyse,verbose,buffers)
select  raw."time",raw.device,raw.therm_temp,raw.therm_temp_sd,
           raw."temp",cal.tair,cal.tair_version,cal.rh
           ,i_s.t_u14,i_s.t_u21 
from device_data.calibrated cal
join device_data.raw raw on cal."time"=raw."time"  and cal.device =raw.device and cal."location" =raw."location" 
join device_data.internal_sensors i_s on cal.device =i_s.device  and cal."location"=i_s."location" and cal."time"=i_s.time
where cal.time >= now()-interval '100 day'
```

Comment: Could you share the complete result (in plain text) from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query?

Comment: Can you use https://explain.depesz.com/ to properly format your explain output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the **real** (and complete) execution plan. Not a summary using some made-up syntax

Comment: The query using the 10-day-interval has to read (and process) 31GB, this takes a while. Using a 100-day interval, that could be hundreds of GB's and a sequential scan might be the smarter solution. The query plan is also way of, it expects 1 single row, but finds 9067714 rows... Are the stats up to date? Please use ANALYZE or check pg_stat_user_tables. Some customer stats using CREATE STATISTICS might help as well to get a better query plan. But, if you have to process hundreds of GB's of data, it will never be fast.

Comment: Thanks Frank.. The stats is update date. I want to create csv file and load this to s3 bucket(in aws). for this I am using aws_s3.query_export_to_s3. what is the best solution to achieve this.

Comment: When a single bucket of 100 days doesn't work, but a small bucket of 10 days does work, just create 10 small buckets covering these 100 days